# Formatting Chapter to fit whole document

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, footer

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and currently using it to write a short thesis. I'm facing the problem that the footer of each chapter page does not fit the style of the rest of the document. In addition I want the footer of the chapter containing the abstract to be formatted with the default style of frontmatter. I know that most of my chapters use the default style `plain` but that is not the desired behaviour. They should just have the footers like the rest of the pages (except frontmatter and Abstract)...

Here is some code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
\rfoot{Seite \thepage}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Abstract}
\mainmatter
\chapter{X}
\chapter{Y}
\chapter{Z}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `\titleformat`... you're probably missing a package that provides that functionality. Instead of providing "some code," can you provide a minimal document that replicates your current behaviour? And then be explicit about what you want and what you don't want. Like, I want the current "Page iv" to be numbered "4", not "iv" and the page number should be in the centre of the footer...

Comment: It is not clear to me how you want the footers to look. Usually the footer of a chapter page is different from the footers of other pages, unless you do someting.